# Want to make a list of all 4 character combinations of 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'

Tags: python, string, ascii, permutation, python-itertools

i want to make a list of all possible combinations of the letters of the alphabet and all numbers, so starting at

`aaaa aaab aaac aaad aaae`
all the way up to
`z999 zzz9 0009`
and everything in between

I've already got

```
import sys
import os

tester = open(r"available.txt","a")
lol =[:100]
['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

lol=list(itertools.combinations(4))

for comb in lol:
    tester.write(str(comb))
```

and similar lines, but they all seem to have an error.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh! I have an algorithm for this... for C++... https://ideone.com/UpwKvC

Comment: Wouldn't the last few be 9997, 9998, 9999?

Comment: _but they all seem to have an error_ Show us the errors, instead of vaguely saying that you got an error.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
"they all seem to have an error" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Also, please read the documentation for `itertools`.  It has other methods that cover exactly this use case.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  We expect you to finish this research before posting here.  Please do so and update your post -- or, if you solved your problem, simply delete it.

Answer (score 2):

You should checkout itertools

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

```
import itertools
itertools.combinations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',4)
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'f'), ... ]
```

```
[ "".join(c) for c in itertools.combinations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',4) ]
['abcd', 'abce', 'abcf', 'abcg', 'abch', ...]
```

The docs show the difference between the various options, depending on if order or duplication is important

```
product('ABCD', repeat=2)
AA AB AC AD BA BB BC BD CA CB CC CD DA DB DC DD

permutations('ABCD', 2)
AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC

combinations('ABCD', 2)
AB AC AD BC BD CD

combinations_with_replacement('ABCD', 2)
AA AB AC AD BB BC BD CC CD DD
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `itertools.product` function. Also, while it's not necessary, I would suggest using `string` for all the characters

```py
import string
import itertools

chars = string.digits+string.ascii_lowercase
orderings = list(itertools.product(chars, repeat=4))
```